# bash - remove all directories (and contents) but not files in pwd

Tags: linux, bash, mingw

I'd like to remove all directories from the pwd but leave the files in the pwd alone. If the content of my pwd is:

```
mydir1
mydir2
myfile1
myfile2
```

then I'd like to be left with just

```
myfile1
myfile2
```

I assume that I need to use `rm -r -i`

Am I correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No that would give you "missing operand" since you didn't specify anything. Putting a `*` would prompt also for files.

I'd give a try to:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

The `mindepth 1` will exclude `.` from the results, the `maxdepth 1` will exclude trying to do under the directories that will anyway get deleted (therefore creating a warning). But in practice you could leave them both out if you agree to have a few "innocent" warnings.

Answer (score 32):

I found this one somewhere:

```
rm -r */
```

Seems the easiest way to go. With your example, you would have to confirm each case, if you have 5 files it's OK, but with bigger file structures an interactive mode is't the way to go... Just as a suggestion, if it's important information, make a backup...

Comment: That will also follow symbolic links, which very probably isn't desired here.

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
rm -rf ./*/
```

That avoids interactive mode an deletes only directories in your local directory.

Comment: As [J­de­B­P pointed out](https://superuser.com/q/713741/150988#comment912645_713746) on [Martin's very similar answer](https://superuser.com/q/713741/150988#713746),  if the current (top-level) directory contains symbolic links to other directories, they will also be deleted (even if they aren't in or subordinate to the current directory).

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

`find /path -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`

-type d looks for only directories

Answer (score -1):

```
you can also try in this way to delete only all folders not files from any location in linux.

    #delete only all dir and don't touch files
    #!/bin/bash
    for dir in `ls -l | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}'`
    do
    echo "going to delete $dir " `rm -rf $dir`
    done
    ls
```